# Set notation and translation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been checking my understanding of sets by setting up the following for myself:

1. $\{ 1, 3, 5, 7, ... \}$ = the set of all natural odd numbers
2. $\{ ..., -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, ... \}$ = the set of all even integers
3. $\{ n\ |\ n = 2m\ \text{for some}\ m\ \text{in}\ \mathbb{N} \}$ = the set of all natural even numbers
4. $\{ n\ |\ n = 2m\ \text{for some}\ m\ \text{in}\ \mathbb{N},\ \text{and}\ n = 3k\ \text{for some}\ k\ \text{in}\ \mathbb{N} \}$ = the set of all natural even numbers which are multiples of 3
5. $\{ w\ |\ w\ \text{is a string of 0s and 1s and}\ w\ \text{equals the reverse of}\ w \}$ = the set of all palindromes of 0s and 1s
6. $\{ n\ |\ n\ \text{is an integer and}\ n=n+1 \}$ = the empty set

Can you check if my understanding is correct?

Comment: All are correct, though 4 has a simpler description...

Comment: $4$ has a simpler description, indeed. But finding it has little to do with sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 can be described as $\{n \space | \space n = 2(3m)= 6m$ where $m \in N \}$

Because if you think about it.

A multiple of $3$ is odd then even then odd then even then odd and so on

$$3,6,9,12,15,18,........$$

And so we are skipping all odd multiples of $3$ and bascially we now have multiples of 6
$$6,12,18,24,30......$$

Comment: U are very welcome :)